# Facial landmarks with dlib, OpenCV, and Python

Tags: python, opencv, dlib, facial-identification

what I'm trying to do using OpenCV, dlib, and Python is to basically identify facial landmarks on a set of images using dlib [from this blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/)

Here is my code:

```
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2

# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
# the facial landmark predictor
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("C:\\Users\SONY\pycharmProjects\multiclass_face_recognition\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")


# load the input image, resize it, and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\SONY\PycharmProjects\multiclass_face_recognition\images\example_01.jpg")
print("the image readed")
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
print("the image resized")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print("the image converted to gray")
print(gray)

# detect faces in the grayscale image
rects = detector(gray, 1)
print("the image detected")
# loop over the face detections
for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
    # array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)


    (x, y, w, h) = face_utils.rect_to_bb(rect)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # show the face number
    cv2.putText(image, "Face #{}".format(i + 1), (x - 10, y - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # loop over the (x, y)-coordinates for the facial landmarks
    # and draw them on the image
    for (x, y) in shape:
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

# show the output image with the face detections + facial landmarks
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now, I don't get any message error, the script run, but it stopped and get crashed. I know the problem in reading the image, because it printed the message before this step, as soon as reach the reading image, it will print some part of it and crashed. I'm sure all paths are correct and the evidence it reads and print some part of image and cannot return NonType Object error, It gives window message of check online solution or stop the program and when I checked online solution, it cannot give me any result. the message as follow:

[image]

Any ideas and suggestions will help me. Thanks alot

Comment: Try to debug and see if you get the correct detector and predictor

    `print detector` and `print predictor`; they must be not NonType

Comment: @thachnb thanks for your reply, yeah you are right, I knew the problem with my dlib installation that give me the following error "failed to build boost.build build engine". can you please please help me with the steps of building boost, I'm tried vary steps, but failed with me.

Comment: Please post the way you install dlib

Comment: I have already fixed the problem, it was in the versions and installation way of some libraries that are wrong. I reinstalled dlib from "https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-windows/" . thanks alot @thachnb

Comment: Great! you're welcome